# Why do mathematicians use $\oplus$ instead of $+$?

Tags: notation, math-history

What is the historical reason for using $\oplus$ instead of $+$ to denote operations that are generally thought of as addition? Similarly, why is $\otimes$ used instead of $\times$ (or just $\cdot$) to denote operations generally thought of as multiplication?

Comment: So you won't confuse them with $+$ and $\times$?

Comment: In general, $\otimes$ and $\oplus$ are not user for such things. They are rather used for operations on algebraic objects such as rings, groups, algebras and modules.

Comment: The symbol $\oplus$ is not synonymous with $+$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The question is why did mathematicians of old not overload $+$ and $\times$ to algebraic objects as well?

Comment: @nathey: Sometimes we do overload those symbols. Other times it is important to make a distinction. This is not a mysterious issue, it is a simple question of people writing in a way that communicates their meaning.

Comment: @nathey: They did.  Then they come up with some different operations on algebraic objects that were also analogous to addition and multiplication, and needed new symbols to distinguish them.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Let me kow if I missunderstood you: Aren't these operations satisfying all on addition and multiplication as well? Regard the category of vector spaces for simplicity. That itself can be endowed with addition and multiplication taking its objects as elements. These will satisfy up to isomorphism all properties expected on addition and multiplication from associativity, commutativity up to distributivity. Especially zero will be the trivial space and one the field itself.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Do you have an example at hand?

Answer (score 14):

If $A$ and $B$ are modules over a ring, their direct product $A \times B$ and their tensor product $A \otimes B$ are different things, so it would be unhelpful to use the same notation for them.

Answer (score 11):

These symbols have different meanings in different contexts. For instance, if we are talking about vector spaces then saying $V=U+W$ is different from $V=U\oplus W$

Comment: Oh yeah, at least one case where $+$ and $\oplus$ coexist.

Comment: I'm assuming that was meant to be condescending. Can you give me an instance you speak of where $\oplus$ is used for something "generally thought of as addition"?

Comment: $\oplus$ isn't used anywhere for addition, but the question is why shouldn't it be? The answer is because of places where the two clash like this.

Answer (score 0):

Besides customary uses, I've seen it used to emphathize the differences of two types of addition, for example: $(\alpha \oplus \beta)A+B$.

The $\oplus$ refers to regular scalar addition, and the $+$ refers to matrix addition.